# Is it possible to quickly get offset (xy) of the clicked object in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I wonder if it is possible to see the offset (from the top left corner of the document) of clicked (selected) object in Photoshop, the way it for example shows current coordinates of the cursor in the info palette?